# How to find and replace in the between start and close function in notepad++

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

I have a problem about find and replace in notepad++

I want to find a space+space in text and replace with just one space. But my area i want to find and replace is between start function and close function (ex: `<div>...</div>`). My file is .xml so it have alot of function.

So please help me. Thanks for your great help :)

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the selected area, Ctrl+F for Find, hit the Replace tab, make sure the In Selection box beside Replace All is ticked.